# CUDA:cudaDeviceSynchronize return error code 30

Tags: cuda

The Code below is about Sha-1 algorithm.

There is a big Loop in kernel(HashRounds=0x40000,262144 times).
Now the situation is ：

1.when running under debug mode,it will report error 30.but if i reduce the cycle time,like 50000 times,no error will be reported.

2.when running under release mode,it is normal.but when i increase the thread scale,like block = 48,thread = 192, it will report the same problem.

Environment:GTX560Ti+Win8+Visual Studio 2012+Cuda5.5

Pleading for your help！！

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
typedef unsigned int    uint32;
typedef unsigned char   byte;
typedef struct {
    uint32 state[5];
    uint32 count[2];
    byte buffer[64];
    byte workspace[64]; // Temporary buffer.
} hash_context;

#define rol(value, bits) (((value) << (bits)) | ((value) >> (32 - (bits))))
/* blk0() and blk() perform the initial expand. */
/* I got the idea of expanding during the round function from SSLeay */

#define blk0(i) (block->l[i] = (rol(block->l[i],24)&0xFF00FF00) \
    |(rol(block->l[i],8)&0x00FF00FF))

#define blk(i) (block->l[i&15] = rol(block->l[(i+13)&15]^block->l[(i+8)&15] \
    ^block->l[(i+2)&15]^block->l[i&15],1))

/* (R0+R1), R2, R3, R4 are the different operations used in SHA1 */
#define R0(v,w,x,y,z,i) {z+=((w&(x^y))^y)+blk0(i)+0x5A827999+rol(v,5);w=rol(w,30);}
#define R1(v,w,x,y,z,i) {z+=((w&(x^y))^y)+blk(i)+0x5A827999+rol(v,5);w=rol(w,30);}
#define R2(v,w,x,y,z,i) {z+=(w^x^y)+blk(i)+0x6ED9EBA1+rol(v,5);w=rol(w,30);}
#define R3(v,w,x,y,z,i) {z+=(((w|x)&y)|(w&x))+blk(i)+0x8F1BBCDC+rol(v,5);w=rol(w,30);}
#define R4(v,w,x,y,z,i) {z+=(w^x^y)+blk(i)+0xCA62C1D6+rol(v,5);w=rol(w,30);}

cudaError_t addWithCuda();
__global__ void cryptKernel();
__device__ void hash_initial(hash_context* context);
__device__ void hash_process( hash_context * context, byte * data, size_t len);
__device__ void SHA1Transform(uint32 state[5], byte workspace[64], byte buffer[64]);

int main()
{
    cudaError_t cudaStatus = addWithCuda();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addWithCuda failed!");
        return 1;
    }
    // cudaDeviceReset must be called before exiting in order for profiling and
    // tracing tools such as Nsight and Visual Profiler to show complete traces.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceReset();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceReset failed!");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("over");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
// Helper function for using CUDA to add vectors in parallel.
cudaError_t addWithCuda()
{
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;
    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    cudaStatus = cudaSetDevice(0);
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaSetDevice failed!  Do you have a CUDA-capable GPU installed?");
        goto Error;
    }
    cryptKernel<<<1,1>>>();
    // Check for any errors launching the kernel
    cudaStatus = cudaGetLastError();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "addKernel launch failed: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaStatus));
        goto Error;
    }
    // cudaDeviceSynchronize waits for the kernel to finish, and returns
    // any errors encountered during the launch.
    cudaStatus = cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    if (cudaStatus != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "cudaDeviceSynchronize returned error code %d after launching addKernel!\n", cudaStatus);
        goto Error;
    }
Error:
    return cudaStatus;
}

__global__ void cryptKernel()
{
    int i = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;
    byte RawPsw[24] = {'\0'};
    hash_context c;
    hash_initial(&c);
    const int HashRounds=0x40000;
    for (int I=0;I<HashRounds;I++)
    {
        hash_process( &c, RawPsw, 24);
    }
}

__device__ void SHA1Transform(uint32 state[5], byte workspace[64], byte buffer[64])
{
    uint32 a, b, c, d, e;
    typedef union {
        byte c[64];
        uint32 l[16];
    } CHAR64LONG16;
    CHAR64LONG16* block;
    block = (CHAR64LONG16*)buffer;
    /* Copy context->state[] to working vars */
    a = state[0];
    b = state[1];
    c = state[2];
    d = state[3];
    e = state[4];
    /* 4 rounds of 20 operations each. Loop unrolled. */
    R0(a,b,c,d,e, 0); R0(e,a,b,c,d, 1); R0(d,e,a,b,c, 2); R0(c,d,e,a,b, 3);
    R0(b,c,d,e,a, 4); R0(a,b,c,d,e, 5); R0(e,a,b,c,d, 6); R0(d,e,a,b,c, 7);
    R0(c,d,e,a,b, 8); R0(b,c,d,e,a, 9); R0(a,b,c,d,e,10); R0(e,a,b,c,d,11);
    R0(d,e,a,b,c,12); R0(c,d,e,a,b,13); R0(b,c,d,e,a,14); R0(a,b,c,d,e,15);
    R1(e,a,b,c,d,16); R1(d,e,a,b,c,17); R1(c,d,e,a,b,18); R1(b,c,d,e,a,19);
    R2(a,b,c,d,e,20); R2(e,a,b,c,d,21); R2(d,e,a,b,c,22); R2(c,d,e,a,b,23);
    R2(b,c,d,e,a,24); R2(a,b,c,d,e,25); R2(e,a,b,c,d,26); R2(d,e,a,b,c,27);
    R2(c,d,e,a,b,28); R2(b,c,d,e,a,29); R2(a,b,c,d,e,30); R2(e,a,b,c,d,31);
    R2(d,e,a,b,c,32); R2(c,d,e,a,b,33); R2(b,c,d,e,a,34); R2(a,b,c,d,e,35);
    R2(e,a,b,c,d,36); R2(d,e,a,b,c,37); R2(c,d,e,a,b,38); R2(b,c,d,e,a,39);
    R3(a,b,c,d,e,40); R3(e,a,b,c,d,41); R3(d,e,a,b,c,42); R3(c,d,e,a,b,43);
    R3(b,c,d,e,a,44); R3(a,b,c,d,e,45); R3(e,a,b,c,d,46); R3(d,e,a,b,c,47);
    R3(c,d,e,a,b,48); R3(b,c,d,e,a,49); R3(a,b,c,d,e,50); R3(e,a,b,c,d,51);
    R3(d,e,a,b,c,52); R3(c,d,e,a,b,53); R3(b,c,d,e,a,54); R3(a,b,c,d,e,55);
    R3(e,a,b,c,d,56); R3(d,e,a,b,c,57); R3(c,d,e,a,b,58); R3(b,c,d,e,a,59);
    R4(a,b,c,d,e,60); R4(e,a,b,c,d,61); R4(d,e,a,b,c,62); R4(c,d,e,a,b,63);
    R4(b,c,d,e,a,64); R4(a,b,c,d,e,65); R4(e,a,b,c,d,66); R4(d,e,a,b,c,67);
    R4(c,d,e,a,b,68); R4(b,c,d,e,a,69); R4(a,b,c,d,e,70); R4(e,a,b,c,d,71);
    R4(d,e,a,b,c,72); R4(c,d,e,a,b,73); R4(b,c,d,e,a,74); R4(a,b,c,d,e,75);
    R4(e,a,b,c,d,76); R4(d,e,a,b,c,77); R4(c,d,e,a,b,78); R4(b,c,d,e,a,79);
    /* Add the working vars back into context.state[] */
    state[0] += a;
    state[1] += b;
    state[2] += c;
    state[3] += d;
    state[4] += e;
}
__device__ void hash_initial(hash_context* context)
{
    /* SHA1 initialization constants */
    context->state[0] = 0x67452301;
    context->state[1] = 0xEFCDAB89;
    context->state[2] = 0x98BADCFE;
    context->state[3] = 0x10325476;
    context->state[4] = 0xC3D2E1F0;
    context->count[0] = context->count[1] = 0;
}
/* Run your data through this. */
__device__ void hash_process( hash_context * context, byte * data, size_t len)
{
    unsigned int i, j;
    uint32 blen = ((uint32)len)<<3;

    j = (context->count[0] >> 3) & 63;
    if ((context->count[0] += blen) < blen ) context->count[1]++;
    context->count[1] += (uint32)(len >> 29);
    if ((j + len) > 63) {
        memcpy(&context->buffer[j], data, (i = 64-j));
        SHA1Transform(context->state, context->workspace, context->buffer);
        for ( ; i + 63 < len; i += 64) {

            SHA1Transform(context->state, context->workspace, &data[i]);

        }
        j = 0;
    }
    else i = 0;
    if (len > i)
      memcpy(&context->buffer[j], &data[i], len - i);
}
```

Comment: In first case it seems like your kernel is killed by watchdog timer Are you using same GPU for driving display? What OS do you use?

Comment: You are hitting the windows TDR mechanism. When your kernel takes too long to execute, windows resets the display driver and GPU. After that your app receives an error from the CUDA API.

Comment: Thanks so much @RobertCrovella ,it is indeed the TDR problem.i turn off the TDR and it works

Comment: Thanks a lot @aland , it is the TDR problem.and i did not use the GPU for dirving display

Comment: @aland or hujun21 if you would like to post an answer, please do so.  Otherwise I will post an answer so we can get this off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 3):

When i increase the loop time or the thread scale,it reports error code 30.It means that the kernel takes so long to execute .So, it hits the windows TDR mechanism.Turn off the TDR will solve this problem.